# Search tag for grid - 'or' condition on two fields/columns

Tags: channel-entries, search, grid

I have created a channel named as 'XYZ'  and having following channel fields there :

```
1) user_type : text 


2) profile : grid

    a) first_name : text 

    b) last_name :  text

    c) user_name : text 

    d) age : text
```

Now i want to show user listing for a entry and i am having a text box in form and i want to search users from first_name or last name.
i have used following code :

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="xyz" entry_id=1}
    {profile search:first_name="amit" search:last_name="amit"}
        {profile:first_name}<br/>
        {profile:last_name}<br/>
        {profile:user_name}<br/>
        {profile:age}<hr>
    {/profile}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

But the code

{profile search:first_name="amit" search:last_name="amit"}

it is using 'and' condition but i want to use 'or' condition.

Comment: Would using a conditional in the results work for you instead of a search? i.e.: {if profile:first_name == "amit" OR profile:last_name == "amit"}...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create custom query and it is ee bug and did not work such for OR conditions.
Use custom query or query module and need to use join with channel and channel field and channel field data etc,